# Type error: cannot read property length from null

Tags: google-apps-script

We have had a sheet that gets data for a quality of work form. This has run flawlessly for over a year now, nothing at all with the sheets, form or script has ever changed since then.

But for some reason, I am now getting an error whenever we run the `SendEmail` function:

`TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null. (line 83, file "SendEmail")`

This is where the error is now happening:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
```

The first column (Item) should have sequential numbers entered automatically whenever the script is run. Nut this now all stays blank and the email template never gets emailed.

````
function SendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 19);
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getMaxRows();
  for (var x = 0; x < dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 2; ++x) {
      if(dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 3).getValue()!=""){
        if(dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 15).getValue()==""){
             var EMInum = dataSheet.getRange((x + 1), 1).getValue() + 1;
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 1).setValue(EMInum);
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 2).setFormula("=\"QoW-\"&text(A" + (x+2) + ",\"000\")");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 15).setFormula("=vlookup(I" + (x+2) + ",ContactDetails,2,0)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 16).setFormula("=vlookup(I" + (x+2) + ",ContactDetails,3,0)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 17).setFormula("=match(J" + (x+2) + ",CompanyName,1)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 18).setFormula("=vlookup(I" + (x+2) + ",ContactDetails,Q" + (x+2) + ",0)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 19).setFormula("=vlookup(I" + (x+2) + ",ContactDetails,Q" + (x+2) + "+1,0)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 27).setFormula("=I" + (x+2)+ "&if(Z" + (x+2)+ "=\"\" ,\" OPEN\",\" CLOSED\")");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 28).setFormula("=if(right(AA" + (x+2) + ",4)=\"OPEN\",now()-datevalue(I" + (x+2)+ "),0)");
             dataSheet.getRange(x+2, 29).setFormula("=if(AB" + (x+2) + "=0,\"e) Closed\",if(AB" + (x+2) + "<90,\"a) 0 - 90 days\",if(AB" + (x+2) + "<180,\"b) 90 - 180 days\",if(AB" + (x+2) + "<360,\"c) 180 - 360 days\",\"d) Over 360 days\"))))");
             //Browser.msgBox("");
          }
        }
      }  

  //


  //


  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var defaultCCAddress = templateSheet.getRange("B17").getValue(); // Added by zumzum as per projectid:a0CD000000xFxWQ

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];

    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    var emailSubject = "NO REPLY: EM&I Quality of Work Issue Submission " + dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 2).getValue();
    var emailCheck = dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 13).getValue();
    //Browser.msgBox(emailCheck);
    var emailAddress = dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 18).getValue();
    var ccemailAddress = dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 15).getValue();
    if(emailCheck=="")
    {
      /* original code commented by zumzum as per projectid:a0CD000000xFxWQ
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText,{cc:ccemailAddress+",david.mortlock@emialliance.com,peter.gresty@emialliance.com",bcc:"richard.priddes@emialliance.com"});
      dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 13).setValue("sent - " + Date());
      */
      // Start od new code added by zumzum as per projectid:a0CD000000xFxWQ
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText,{cc:ccemailAddress+","+defaultCCAddress}); 
      dataSheet.getRange(i + 2, 13).setValue("sent - " + Date()); 
      // End of new code added by zumzum as per projectid:a0CD000000xFxWQ
    }   
  }
}


// Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
// Arguments:
//   - template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
//   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
//           data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
// Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
// simply removed.
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
  var email = template;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
  var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);

  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
  for (var i = 1; i < templateVars.length; i++) {
    // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
    var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
    email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
  }

  return email;
}





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}```
````

Comment: We need to see what `templateVars` is assigned to since that's what's `null`.  We also need to know what was creating the sequential numbers: was it a script function, or a Sheets function in a cell that someone deleted by accident maybe?

Comment: Hi There. Yes its the script function that creates the sequential numbers. How do i see what the templatevars was or is assigned to?

Comment: Can you add more code (or all the code) to your question?  We don't have enough info as it is. If you post all the code, we can point out what templateVars is assigned to. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Full code added. Please ignore the missing function right at the top of the code, it is there but couldnt get it in the code here.

Comment: Follow the steps detailed here: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting can be reproduced by running `fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData)` with any string for `emailTemplate` that does not contain a placeholder in the form `${"foo"}` (the literal double quotes are required per the regex `/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g`).

In `SendEmail`, the value for `emailTemplate` is coming from the first sheet, cell A1.  Check what value you have in that cell.  Does it contain templates in the correct `${"foo"}` form?

Since this error can be caused by a user manipulating the spreadsheet, consider improving `fillInTemplateFromObject` by checking for a successful `match` before trying to use the expected array.

```js
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
  var email = template;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
  var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);
  if (! templateVars) {
    throw new Error("No templates found in your template sheet.  Aborting.")
  }
  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
  for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; i++) {
    // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
    var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
    email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
  }

  return email;
}
```

You can catch that error in `SendEmail` and provide even more useful information:

```js
// inside SendEmail
try {
  var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error("In spreadsheet " + ss.getUrl() + " sheet " + templateSheet.getSheetName() + " row " + (i+1) + " there were no templates found.")
}
```

If you still need help debugging the error, [use the apps script debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) or use the [various logging options built into apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#logging) to output the state of your data at run time.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using ++i rather than i++? My guess is this is the problem, if templateVars is an array, you are getting to the end of the array and trying to run it once on a row that doesn't exist. Maybe before, this was an empty row, but now the last row is the end of the sheet.

Knowing nothing else about your code I'd change:

```
for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 1; i < templateVars.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Hi J.G. Many thanks. I tried that change but it still gives me the same error.

// Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
// Arguments:
//   - template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
//   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
//           data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
// Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
// simply removed.
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
  var email = template;

Comment: @Paul Zumzum you should put this code in your question.  Is it possible you are not using any `${"template"}` in your input?  That might explain why `templateVars` is null.

Comment: Full code added. Please ignore the missing function right at the top, it is there but couldnt get it in the code here.